# Heroku App - Check logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

i have a problem with my heroku app in some sections of the app in Posts/1 or some post created:

`We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.`

This is my app link: forum-epic.herokuapp.com

I do in my terminal: $ heroku logs:

`` 2014-03-15T01:59:40.967235+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-15T01:59:40.966710+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in call'
2014-03-15T01:59:40.966710+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:inblock in start_thread'
2014-03-15T01:59:40.967235+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-15T01:59:41.968384+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/posts/new host=forum-epic.herokuapp.com request_id=4b173bf1-6156-43f9-ab71-b2fbb7396e03 fwd="187.253.215.208" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=10ms status=304 bytes=805
2014-03-15T01:59:42.148134+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-d0b54dd563966c42aad5fd85b1c1f713.css host=forum-epic.herokuapp.com request_id=ecd6b6b4-2901-44c2-8e9e-c65e860a4a78 fwd="187.253.215.208" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=1616
2014-03-15T01:59:42.162296+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-f472f62f2e8bac4049be455c1a6b8f1d.js host=forum-epic.herokuapp.com request_id=a971770a-7395-47ca-a21e-44a67ee4166c fwd="187.253.215.208" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=1616
2014-03-15T02:00:00.489023+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/posts host=forum-epic.herokuapp.com request_id=c340ccda-0237-43ea-82c9-3ae99787a54b fwd="187.253.215.208" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=44ms status=401 bytes=909
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577027+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-03-15T01:59:40.967633 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/assets/application-f472f62f2e8bac4049be455c1a6b8f1d.js" for 187.253.215.208 at 2014-03-15 01:59:40 +0000
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577027+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2014-03-15T01:59:40.969043 #2] FATAL -- : 
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577027+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in call'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577027+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:incall'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577027+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application-f472f62f2e8bac4049be455c1a6b8f1d.js"):
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577027+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in block in call'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577027+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:intagged'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577249+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in call'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577027+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:intagged'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577249+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in call'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577249+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:incall'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577249+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in call'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577419+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:inservice'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577419+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in run'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577027+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:incall_app'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577027+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in block in tagged'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577249+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:incall'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577249+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in call'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577249+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:incall'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577249+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in call'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577419+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577419+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-03-15T01:59:41.959347 #2]  INFO -- :   Rendered posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577419+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:inblock in start_thread'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577419+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-03-15T01:59:41.955034 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/posts/new" for 187.253.215.208 at 2014-03-15 01:59:41 +0000
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577419+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-03-15T01:59:41.956171 #2]  INFO -- : Processing by PostsController#new as HTML
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577249+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in call'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577884+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:incall'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577884+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application-d0b54dd563966c42aad5fd85b1c1f713.css"):
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577884+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2014-03-15T01:59:42.139182 #2] FATAL -- : 
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577884+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in block in call'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577884+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:inblock in tagged'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577419+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in service'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577249+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:incall'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577884+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in tagged'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577884+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:incall_app'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577884+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in tagged'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578079+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:incall'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578079+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in call'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578079+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:incall'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578079+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in call'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578410+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:inservice'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578410+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578410+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in call'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578583+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:incall_app'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578079+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in call'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578583+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:inblock in call'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578079+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in call'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578583+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:intagged'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578410+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in service'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577419+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-03-15T01:59:41.960067 #2]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 3.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578583+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:incall'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578900+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in call'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578410+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:inblock in start_thread'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578410+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-03-15T01:59:42.152295 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/assets/application-f472f62f2e8bac4049be455c1a6b8f1d.js" for 187.253.215.208 at 2014-03-15 01:59:42 +0000
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578410+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in run'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578900+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:incall'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578900+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in call'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578900+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:incall'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578900+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in block in start_thread'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.579068+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-03-15T02:00:00.449231 #2]  INFO -- : Started POST "/posts" for 187.253.215.208 at 2014-03-15 02:00:00 +0000
2014-03-15T02:00:00.579068+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577419+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578410+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application-f472f62f2e8bac4049be455c1a6b8f1d.js"):
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578900+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:incall'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.579068+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-03-15T02:00:00.483839 #2]  INFO -- : Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
2014-03-15T02:00:00.579068+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-03-15T02:00:00.484007 #2]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"BsOc6lEqHf56jK80dlHPPJbUyxdTdZ4OjMhTn4QViX0=", "post"=>{"title"=>"Test - Primer Post", "text"=>"Test - Primer Text"}, "commit"=>"Save Post"}
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578583+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in block in tagged'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.579068+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-03-15T02:00:00.575765 #2]  INFO -- : Started POST "/posts" for 187.253.215.208 at 2014-03-15 02:00:00 +0000
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578079+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:incall'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577884+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-03-15T01:59:42.138231 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/assets/application-d0b54dd563966c42aad5fd85b1c1f713.css" for 187.253.215.208 at 2014-03-15 01:59:42 +0000
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578079+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in call'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.579068+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-03-15T02:00:00.576886 #2]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"BsOc6lEqHf56jK80dlHPPJbUyxdTdZ4OjMhTn4QViX0=", "post"=>{"title"=>"Test - Primer Post", "text"=>"Test - Primer Text"}, "commit"=>"Save Post"}
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578900+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:inrun'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578410+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2014-03-15T01:59:42.153295 #2] FATAL -- : 
2014-03-15T02:00:00.577884+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in call'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578583+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:incall'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578583+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in tagged'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.579068+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-03-15T02:00:00.484920 #2]  INFO -- : Filter chain halted as #<Proc:0x007fbfea3bbbe8@/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb:71> rendered or redirected
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578583+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:incall'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578079+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in call'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578583+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:incall'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.579068+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-15T02:00:00.579068+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-03-15T02:00:00.576783 #2]  INFO -- : Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578900+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in service'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578079+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:incall'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578900+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in service'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578410+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578583+00:00
 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:incall'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.578900+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-03-15T02:00:00.579068+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-03-15T02:00:00.485104 #2]  INFO -- : Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-03-15T02:00:00.598183+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/posts host=forum-epic.herokuapp.com request_id=0113c1f4-9fb0-45ba-83c9-77dc456143fd fwd="187.253.215.208" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=23ms status=302 bytes=946
2014-03-15T02:00:00.870347+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/posts/1 host=forum-epic.herokuapp.com request_id=35d4abfc-e688-4997-806f-45264d8147f9 fwd="187.253.215.208" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=24ms status=500 bytes=1543
2014-03-15T02:00:07.379621+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/posts/1 host=forum-epic.herokuapp.com request_id=f41315f4-4b50-4ba3-858e-2c3fd8af0cce fwd="187.253.215.208" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=47ms status=500 bytes=1543 ``

Edit:This is the guide of Rails and i push in heroku master.

What can i do? Im new in heroku and i don't know how fix it, i hope some can help me. Thanks.

Comment: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application-f472f62f2e8bac4049be455c1a6b8f1d.js")` This line may give you some insight into your problem. Heroku has some setup needed to get assets precompiling, depending on where you are serving them. Check out this link: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

Comment: Tx for the answer John, but this doesn't works, the error keep appearing :/

Answer (score 0):

run these commands when you deploy your application to heroku

```
heroku run rake assets:clean
heroku run rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: Hi Ashish, I wrote in the terminal and it says

Running `rake assests:clean` attached to terminal... up, run.7440
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'assests:clean'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: Theres a typo there, you've spelt `assests` instead of `assets`